# Trying to remove css rule by regex

Tags: java, regex

I got emails and trying to display them on the page in a div. But the mail I got contains body css like `body{background-color: #444}` makes my pages looked wierd. I am trying to remove the `body` rule from css. I use jsoup got the style tag html, the only question is how can I remove the rule by regex?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
String withoutBody = text.replaceAll("body\\s*\\{.*?\\}", "");
```

Notes;

- you must escape the `{}` chars
- in java you must escape the backslash too, that's why they are doubled
- the `?` in `.*?` makes the match non-greedy, which means it won't match with another `}` after the body CSS tag